# Responder not collecting hashes in most cases

Tags: hash, windows, active-directory

I've recently become curious on how AD works and how hashes are shared between Windows machines. It's very interesting how there are so many ways to get Windows programs to leak hashes, for example through editing a word docx settings file so it requests an SMB share whenever it is opened.

I've been testing my school laptop on my personal network and using Responder to see and poison LLMNR and NBT-NS traffic. I learned through [this](https://markclayton.github.io/where-are-my-hashes-responder-observations.html) blog post that Windows will only authenticate using hashes passwords when a new name is navigated to, not an already known name. I was running kali on virtualbox in bridged mode connected to my home network through ethernet. By navigating my school laptop to connect to a SMB share on my personal computer running the VM, I was able to capture the hash with my personal password.

I was with a friend and wanted to show them this. With their complete knowing consent, I attempted to use the same setup, this time using my phone's hotspot as the network. A WiFi card was passed through USB to the kali vm which directly connected to the hotspot and my friend's school laptop was connected as well.

I wasn't able to capture any hashes though. I tried connecting to a fake file share on my friend's laptop and I was able to see the requests on kali but no hashes. I tried connecting to a file share hosted on the my laptop's windows host and you could see the traffic in kali for that too but no hashes were captured either.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Is the process just finicky and won't always work?

Comment: This looks like a networking problem, not a security problem or a problem with Responder. Sort out the network troubleshooting first and run packet captures to confirm.

Comment: Same problem: i can manually catch the hash from Wireshark, but not with Responder. Responder however, does log requests and responses.. but doesn't log hashes.